# How to format build.sbt using scalariform

Tags: scala, sbt, scalariform

I would like to have my 2.11 scala project automatically formatted.

The scala code under `/src/main/scala` seems to be well formated, however, the build.sbt below is not. I would like to align %%, % and =>.

my `project/scalariform.sbt` :

```
resolvers += Resolver.typesafeRepo("releases")

addSbtPlugin("org.scalariform" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.6.0")
```

my `build.sbt` :

```
name := "test"

version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val sparkVersion = "2.0.1"
  val hadoopVersion = "2.7.0"
  Seq("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % Provided,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % Provided,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion % Provided,
    "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % hadoopVersion
  )
}

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Cloudera" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/",
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}

import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtScalariform
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtScalariform.ScalariformKeys

import scalariform.formatter.preferences._

SbtScalariform.scalariformSettings

ScalariformKeys.preferences := ScalariformKeys.preferences.value
  .setPreference(AlignSingleLineCaseStatements, true)
  .setPreference(AlignParameters, true)
  .setPreference(DoubleIndentClassDeclaration, true)
```

Thanks for your help